# Conversion fails between two Generic Types

Tags: c#, linq, generics, types, generic-programming

I am trying to create an object type (MyObject) with a linq expression of type T. My class states that the value of T must be of type BaseModel (which is an object created by me). Below is how MyObject is constructed:

```
public class MyObject<T> where T : BaseModel
{
    public Type MyType;

    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> MyExpression;
}
```

All of my models inherit from BaseModel. Example:

```
public class MyModel : BaseModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My object is used inside of a generic static class:

```
public static class MyStaticClass
{
    private static Dictionary<MyObject<BaseModel>, string> MyDictionary = new Dictionary<MyObject<BaseModel>, string>();

    public static AddMyObjectsToDictionary(List<MyObject<BaseModel>> myObjects)
    {
        //CODE
    }

    //REST OF CODE
}
```

Then when my app loads it does the following **(Error is thrown here)**:

```
List<MyObject<BaseModel>> myObjects = new List<MyObject<BaseModel>>();

myObjects.Add(new MyObject<MyModel>()
{
    MyType = typeof(MyModel),
    MyExpression = p => p.Name == "myname"
});

MyStaticClass.AddMyObjectsToDictionary(myObjects);
```

Exact error message thrown with the namespaces to show in which project each object is located:

> cannot convert from `'ProjectANamespace.MyObject<ProjectBNamespace.MyModel>'` to `'ProjectANamespace.MyObject<ProjectANamespace.BaseModel>'`

I need to be able to create a generic expression within MyModel however I cannot specify MyModel inside of MyStaticClass since it is meant to be a generic class which is located in another project along with BaseModel.

Anyone have any ideas how resolve this issue?

Comment: Is that the _exact_ error message?  I would expect a message that it cannont convert `MyObject<MyModel>` to `MyObject<BaseModel>` since `BaseModel` is invariant.

Comment: No the exact error is:

cannot convert from 'ProjectANamespace.MyObject<ProjectBNamespace.MyModel>' to 'ProjectANamespace.MyObject<ProjectANamespace.BaseModel>'

I included the namespace to show the objects defined in the different projects

Comment: Yes that makes much more sense.  Then the problem is due to `MyObject` being invariant, not because it's not "visible" to the main program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MyObject<MyModel>` isn't a `MyObject<BaseModel>`, just like `List<string>` isn't a `List<object>`. It works the same outside of generics too - the general concept is called *variance*, and describes valid substitution of types. Since `MyObject` is neither co-variant nor contra-variant with respect to `T`, `MyObject<T>` can never be a `MyObject<U>`, for any T and U that aren't the same.

Generic type arguments in interfaces and delegates can be both co-variant and contra-variant, but not both at the same time. For example, your `Func<T, bool>` is contra-variant, because you can substitute a type derived from `T` instead of `T` itself. So a `Func<BaseModel, bool>` can be converted to `Func<MyModel, bool>` (just as `MyModel` can be passed as an argument "instead" of `BaseModel`), but not vice versa. Analogously, `Func<T, U>` is contra-variant with respect to `T` and co-variant with respect to `U` - you can't return `object` from a function that has a return type of `string`.

So even if you changed your definition to use an interface to add variance, you'll only be able to get contra-variance, not the co-variance you want. Too bad - there's no safe way to do that.

Instead, if you need a non-generic interface, just add a non-generic interface. That's it. Instead of `List<MyObject<BaseModel>>`, you'll have `List<IMyObject>`, which you can use as required (probably through casting, or just exposing the simple `Expression` instead of `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`).

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, I believe that you need to use the [Covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) features of c# 4+.  In particular, I believe you need to use the [out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) modifier.  After some testing, I discovered that this will not work for classes.  However, if you introduce an interface into the pattern, you could make this work.  For example, the following compiles

```
public class Base
{

}

public class Derived : Base
{

}

public interface IWrapper<out T> where T : Base
{

}

public class Wrapper<T> : IWrapper<T> where T : Base
{

}

public static class Methods
{
  public static void Test()
  {
    var obj = new List<IWrapper<Base>>();
    obj.Add(new Wrapper<Derived>());
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work because classes are invariant and the `T` parameter in the `Func` is contravariant anyway.

Comment: Very true.  I just tested it and discovered that.  I will edit to match.